# Computing new count variable conditional on index variable

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

I am translating some Stata code to R and am running into some difficulty. I have a data frame:

```
District     pairID    SympXSero    Union       *New Count Variable*
1            1         0            1.4          1    
2            1         1            1.4          1  
3            1         0            1.3          1  
4            3         1            1.5          3   
5            3         1            1.4          3  
6            3         1            1.7          3 
7            2         0            1.4          0  
8            2         0            1.5          0  
9            2         0            1.4          0   
10           4         0            1.5          1    
11           4         0            1.5          1    
12           4         1            1.6          1
```

What I need to accomplish is to create a new count variable within each `pairID`. This new count variable will be the total (for each group of common pairID) of the variable `posXsymp` which takes on values only of 0 or 1. I am working on some code in `dplyr`, but when I run:

```
bdata.raw1 %>%
  group_by(pairID) %>%
  mutate(count_sympsero = sum(posXsymp))
```

It returns the total count for the entire sample, and not within the index variable `pairID`. As context, the Stata code I am attempting to translate is:

```
bys pairID: egen count_sympsero = total(posXsymp)
```

I have attempted a crude example of data and the variable I need to calculate above.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Otherwise his is a bit of a guessing game. It is likely that you are after something like `... %>% mutate(count_sympsero = cumsum(posXsymp)` or perhaps `mutate(count_sympsero = 1:n())`. It's difficult to help without data.

Comment: Have now edited the post with crude sample data and *expected output*.

Comment: So how is `df %>% group_by(PairID) %>% mutate(new_count_variable = sum(SympXSero)) %>% ungroup()` not what you're after? It seems to reproduce your expected output. Is this perhaps a typo issue. Your sample data has column "PairID" (with capital "P") while your code has "pairID" (with a lowercase "p"). This should've thrown an error though.

Comment: Yes, sample data column should have been pairID (now fixed in the post). I think the group_by(pairID)>%>mutate with cumsum argument is indeed what I needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The values in column "*New Count Variable*" are reproduced with `sum(SympXSero)`, not with `cumsum(...)`. Isn't that what you are after?

Comment: My error, it is indeed sum(SympXSero) that reproduced the values I was seeking and are shown in the column "New Count Variable" in the OP.